# Not Able to Generate the XML From XSD File

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd

i tried creating XML file using Schema File but when i try to select the schema file , go on to next step i am not getting the option of the selecting Root element from the Drop down .

XSD File

```
 <element name="patient" type="tns:Patient" />
 <complexType name="Patient">
    <sequence>
        <element name="id" type="int" />
        <element name="name" type="string" />
        <element name="mobile" type="int" />
        <element name="age" type="string" />
        <element name="dob" type="date" />
    </sequence>
 </complexType>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcjxq.png)
i am attaching the screenshot of the image

Comment: That isn't a valid XSD file - there must only be a single XML element at the top level - normally `schema` for XSD.

Comment: That `tns:` in `type="tns:Patient"` looks odd (beside the missing root element in your XSD).